# JPA transaction handling

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data

I have a `Foo` entity with fields `Name`, `SecondaryName` and `Counter`.
In the DB I have a unique constraint on (name, secondaryName, counter).

In the service layer I have the following method (where `fooRepositry` is a `CrudRepository`):

```
 @Transactional(isolation = Isolation.SERIALIZABLE, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
 public void saveFoo(Foo foo) {
    Optional<TestDto> fooWithHighestCounter= fooRepository.
          findTopByNameAndSecondaryNameOrderByCounterDesc(foo.getName(), foo.getSecondaryName());

    if (fooWithHighestCounter.isPresent()) {
        foo.setCounter(fooWithHighestCounter.get().getCounter() + 1);
    } else {
        foo.setCounter(1);
    }

    Foo saved = fooRepository.save(foo);
}
```

With every call on `saveFoo`, a new record shall be created in the DB with already the existing highest counter + 1. Hence, the highest counter must be found, thus the `@Transactional`.

However, I constantly get `ContraintViolationException` when multiple threads call the `saveFoo` method as every thread finds the same highest counter value.

I assumed that every thread would create a new transaction and those transactions will run serially so no transaction would find the same counter value. (The `@EnableTransactionManagement` is put on the Application)

What else can I do to achieve the aforementioned behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the fooRepository.save(foo) at last is saving the same values again and again in the database that is why it is giving `ContrainViolationException`. If you need to update the value to any existing Object just call the setCounter but dont call the `.save()` method instead call the update method of the repository (if you have any) else if it is a new entity which is not present in database yet then call the `save` method.

If it is done in hibernate refer the following link

Ref: http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/persistence/update

Comment: The foo object is not managed, just the fooWithHighestCounter. I want to create a new record in the db with every call to saveFoo(foo), not updating an existing entity. However, the newly created foo object's counter shall be higher than the already existing values in the database.

Comment: Yes the problem is you are doing it in multithreading while one thread is storing the updated counter value other thread have already saved the same and the this new thread is violating the constraint. You have to do row lock on the database

Comment: Why are you repeating the rows with same details only a counter change ? single row can hold the same information.

Comment: Thank you. I thought the Isolation.SERIALIZABLE already maintaining locks. It a part of a bigger application with a history why a new row for every change :)

Comment: Ref: http://makandracards.com/makandra/31937-differences-between-transactions-and-locking

Comment: ref for locking : http://www.developer.com/java/manage-concurrent-access-to-jpa-entity-with-locking.html

Comment: Perhaps same nature of question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1950596/synchronized-method-or-use-spring-transactional